# How to properly write custom header formula in External Credential?

Tags: formula, callout, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

I need to make callout to the Hotel Beds api. For an authentication headers I used External Credentials custom headers.

But it is not properly creates headers(I guess).

Hotel Beds requires following:

- to authenticate, you must send both the API Key and the X-Signature,
- a SHA256 hash in Hex format calculated from your API key, your secret plus current timestamps in seconds.

I added custom header with the following formula:

```
HEX(HASH(\'SHA-256\', 
    BLOB($Credential.Hotel_Beds_External_Credential.apiKey & 
         $Credential.Hotel_Beds_External_Credential.secret & 
         LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(now()),3),2)))))
```

But it did not work. Please, help to build proper formula for custom header in External Credentials.

Comment: Your formula might be correct.  There are [some issues](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409100/salesforce-named-credential-hmac-merge-function-n-new-line-not-work-in-value) with this approach. You're better off starting in Apex. When you have a working Apex implementation, you can try again converting it to a formula and see if this is your issue or a Salesforce bug.